# How can I help Nurse Dorothy Crane in Whitechapel?

Tags: vampyr

Nurse Dorothy Crane calls for the protagonist Dr. Reid's assistance when he encounters her in Whitechapel. Despite Dr. Reid's expertise, he needs your help as the player to dictate a best course of action to his nurse. While I played this sequence, I thought I made reasonable selections as the event played out, but Nurse Crane's responses suggested I made at least one error. Sure enough, a post-procedure examination of the mission checklist shows this objective as failed.

In light of these events, my questions are as follows:

- What is required to succeed at helping Nurse Crane?
- Are there specific consequences for success vs. failure at this objective?

And finally,

- What bearing (if any) does this have on the decision which next presents itself?

Comment: I don't have concrete answers to these questions (because it's impossible to retry things), but I also "failed" this scenario.  I would not be surprised if the player isn't meant to succeed.  Furthermore, after playing several more chapters, I've found that even completely no-brainer how-can-this-possibly-be-the-wrong-thing-to-do decisions lead to surprisingly bad outcomes.  And not in a "I see what you did there" way, but more of a "I see that you forgot to hire a narrative director" way. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it doesn't have any effect on the patient's life (he will die anyway), the correct answers are:

1. **"Anything else I should know?"** instead of "Where are the quinine salts?"
2. **" I must perform a tracheostomy!"** instead of "Do we have anaesthetics?"
3. **"Don't question me!"** instead if "What would you suggest?"
4. **"I must suture the artery"** instead of "Let me finish alone!"
5. **"Epinephrine, now!"** instead of "Cardiac massage, now!"<sup>*</sup>

If done correctly, Nurse Crane will praise you saying that you've done all there could be.

<sup>*I was a bit curious about the last point, since for anyone who ever watched any sort of medical drama, cardiac massage seems like an obvious choice. But in real life, it wasn't widely used until the 1960s, hence Nurse will reply "You making this up?"</sup>